# Add dumping to JS Pendulum

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

There is a good JS Canvas example of Pendulum. It works fun.
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Animate_a_pendulum#JavaScript_.2B_.3Ccanvas.3E
But it works as a "clock" pendulum - it never stops.
How can I stop it, like a simple pendulum usually stops in time ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This realizes the differential equation

```
angle''(t)+k*sin(angle(t))=0
```

Since they use the Euler forward method for integration, the system will actually increase its energy , measured as

```
E = 0.5*angle'(t)^2+k*(1-cos(angle)).
```

To add damping to the equation, you can simulate some air friction by setting

```
acceleration = -k*sin(angle)-c*velocity
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  
But what is a var **c** at your case?(-c*velocity) It does not work without it.